# What Is This Explaining?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Working through Rails Tutorial; I'm in the Rails Console mode, or rather, Development Mode, by running 'rails console'.  I'm following Hartl's great tutorial, and I'm presented with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

when I run: 'nil.empty?'

and in Hartl's tutorial it shows this as being presented after running the command:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?
```

My question is, what is all the additional details with my directory, and the different folders (what it looks like)?

Learning Rails, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to `/Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0`... lines, that's the stacktrace.

Essentially it shows you what went wrong, and the relevant lines of code.

Since you're in the `rails console`, which is essentially [`irb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell), that's what it's saying in the `from (irb):7` line - that's where you called the `empty?` method.

In your case, you attempted to call `empty?` method on something that was apparently an object of the [`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html). Since it doesn't know how to respond to `empty?` it threw a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm really focusing my attention and aiming to grasp especially, is the environment for the creation of an application; ie; development, test, production- that's probably the most important aspect of using these tools.

Comment: My next question would be; if I want to run Spork with Guard, is there a specific command for executing both simultaneously? I know how to run each separately, with 'bundle exec guard', and 'bundle exec spork'; but again, this constitutes only one being established and running. Do I just run 'bundle exec guard', and that will establish both?

Comment: @user2698988 If you follow Michael's specific configuration instructions (assuming they haven't changed substantially from the previous version of the tutorial), running guard will run spork.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're thinking that the distinction between development, test and production is the most important aspect of using these tools. The main usage is to vary which database is used and what software is loaded. The three environments are mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: No, not the distinction; the work-flow that a polished environment on your machine when creating these application is what I currently find the most important- which Hartl has demonstrated beautifully in his tutorial that I am reading.